# How to solve this PDE (Partial Differential Equation) for the following diffusion process?

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I need to find a closed-form solution for the following PDE (a diffusion equation) on $u(x,t)$:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = a\varepsilon^2 (x^2 u_x)_x$$

With  $\varepsilon$ (an asymptotic parameter) and $a$ being real constants.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When Maple is used, it always uses the separation of variables. For example, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/600936) too the same path has been taken. The issue is, is it necessary that the temporal part will always behave exponentially?